# bot3 ecs.execute_command: Task Identifier is invalid

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I have defined a task in AWS ECS. I have copied the task ARN into the API call:

```
rsp = ecs.execute_command(
        container='test',
        command=json.dumps(event),
        task='arn:aws:ecs:##-####-#:############:task-definition/test:1',
        interactive=True
    )
```

I receive the following error complaining about the task identifier:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the ExecuteCommand operation: Task Identifier is invalid
```

I am not sure what is wrong as the task identifier has been copied from the AWS web interface where the task was created. Am I just missing something extremely obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double Check the Components: A valid ECS task ARN looks something like this:

```
arn:aws:ecs:[region]:[account-id]:task/[cluster-name]/[task-id]
```

Distinguish between Task Definition ARN and Task ARN, they are different.

Check if the Task is in the "RUNNING" State

Check your Permission, do you have the correct IAM role?

Comment: This is the issue. I am learning to use Fargate and EC2 tasks so I thought you could just execute the command since it was setup to be run in Fargate. It sounds like the tasks needs to be running somewhere, EC2 or Fargate, before any commands can be run.